# How can I use an out parameter for a struct entry in a 2D array?

Tags: c#

I have a class containing a 2D map of tiles. I want a `TryGetTile()` [similar to `TryGetValue()` from the Dictionary class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,2e5bc6d8c0f21e67). My tiles are structs.

```
public class Map
{

    Tile[,] tiles = new Tile[100, 100];

    public bool TryGetTile (int x, int y, out Tile output)
    {
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < tiles.GetLength(0) && y < tiles.GetLength(1))
        {
            output = tiles[x,y];
            return true;
        }
        output = default(Tile);
        return false;
    }

}

public struct Tile
{
    public int someValue;
}
```

And the expected use would be something like

```
Map someMap = new Map();
if (someMap.TryGetTile(25, 30, out var tile))
{
      tile.someValue += 100;
}
```

This wouldn't work as expected since the returned `Tile` isn't actually a reference to that array entry. I'm aware the structs are passed by value but I thought that this would be equivalent to modifying a reference of `tiles[25,30]`, if that makes any sense.

This will become a non-issue later because I'm also aware that structs should seldom be mutable, so I'll probably end up using classes instead. However I'm curious if there was a way to make this work as desired.

Comment: Not that I can think of. If you had an indexer on your `Map` class, you could do `someMap[25, 30] = new Tile { someValue = tile.someValue + 100 };` Not super elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From C# 7.0 forward, you can do this. You should restrict this type of implementation to performance-critical scenarios, because it makes the code harder to understand, and introduces some awkwardness and risks to the code. But it can be done, using the [Ref returns and ref locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) feature:

```cs
public class Map
{

    static Tile defaultTile = default(Tile);
    Tile[,] tiles = new Tile[100, 100];

    public ref Tile TryGetTile(int x, int y, out bool found)
    {
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < tiles.GetLength(0) && y < tiles.GetLength(1))
        {
            found = true;
            return ref tiles[x, y];
        }

        found = false;
        return ref defaultTile;
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Because you can't have `out ref Tile output` (i.e. no by-reference ref parameters), you'd have to swap the `Tile` and `bool` values, return type vs. parameter.
2. Since you're returning a reference, you have to have a value that you can actually reference, hence the `defaultTile` field. **But be careful!** A `ref` value is an alias to the original variable, which means the caller of this method can modify the `defaultTile` field. Yuck! (You could mitigate this risk a little by reinitializing the field every time you return a reference to it, but that will eat into whatever performance advantage you might have gotten from this strategy.)

Example usage:

```cs
Map map = new Map();

// ref return: these variables are aliases to the elements in the array
ref Tile tile1 = ref map.TryGetTile(10, 10, out bool found1),
    tile2 = ref map.TryGetTile(200, 200, out bool found2);

Console.WriteLine($"found1: {found1}");
Console.WriteLine($"found2: {found2}");
tile1.someValue = 17;

// value return: this variable is a *copy* of the element in the array
Tile tile3 = map.TryGetTile(10, 10, out bool found3);

Console.WriteLine($"tile3.someValue: {tile3.someValue}");
```

This will output the following:

```
found1: True
found2: False
tile3.someValue: 17
```

I.e. the `Tile` value returned and stored in `tile3`, copied from the array, has the value that was set earlier via the `ref Tile` variable `tile1`.

For what it's worth, my personal preference is to use immutable objects wherever possible, even for reference types. This changes the semantics of things like your `TryGetTile()` method, because the caller can never modify the object itself. Instead, your `Map` class also needs to provide a method that will update a `Tile` value. Barring that, it's really better for `Tile` to be a reference type, if you want reference type semantics.

But if you really insist, you can accomplish what you want via the ref local and ref return feature.